# Create ETL JOB using SSIS for the process

Tags: ssis, msbi

Below is my ask.

1. I have a column A in source table that has value 0 and 1.
2. I have created a derived table for that column and associated  column B, and have destination table where there is already associated column which has value  "XYZ" where source column has value = 0.
3. So if value in source table changes from 0 to 1, the destination column will have the value "ABCD", and if the  value changes back from 1 to 0, the destination column should have value "EFGH".
   Pl

Please help me, how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Easiest way is to create trigger, read through Update, insert triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below steps to do the activity.

1. Create a [data flow task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-flow-task?view=sql-server-2017) in SSIS for datamovement
2. Create a source component for extracting data from table
3. Create a [derived column transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) for mapping 0 & 1 accordingly using [SSIS expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-2017)
4. Create a [update OLEDB command transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) for updating the record, based on step no. 3 derived value